# How can I see my LINUX virtual server that I created in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, instance

I am new in AWS, I have created two instances of Linux server on AWS, my question how can I see these virtual servers, how can i connect and visualize them, I hope that you can help me.

Comment: How did you create the ec2 servers?

Comment: What do you mean by "see" and "visualize"?

Answer (score 0):

> how can I see these virtual servers,

You can see your EC2 servers under

```
AWS Console -> Services -> Compute -> EC2
```

On the dashboard you should see your server details.

> how can i connect

When you created the server, you must have used a private key(.pem) file. When you are able to locate your server. You would be able to find the public IP of them and then you ssh into them using

```
ssh -i yourKey.pem ec2-user@yourServerPublicIP
```